# Where is Microsoft Teams application located on my Windows 10 Computer?

Tags: windows-10, path, microsoft-teams, file-location, locate

From the 'tray icon' I chose to disable "start Teams on startup" but now I can't find the application.
It's not in Programs Files > Microsoft [neither in Program Files (x86)].
It's not in App Data for the current user.
It's not in the Start Menu (neither searching through it).
Where is it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not contain within the user's  `..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\` folder?  You can find the location of the file, by running Teams, and using Task Manager and "open file location"

Comment: Yes, mine is located at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe`. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to re-install Teams.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Where is it?

If Microsoft Teams is actually installed then it's contained within `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Teams\current\`.  You can also find it by running the application, and within Task Manager, use "open file location".  If you are unable to run the application or the file is not located in that location then Microsoft Teams is not actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the WindowsApps folder of Program Files:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MSTeams_24046.2809.2757.3796_x64_...\
```